# "Invalid partition table!"

Tags: boot, partitioning

I had a workstation with Ubuntu installed and running for some time in active use.  The workstation did not have any version of Windows and did not dual-boot.  Unfortunately, someone in our office unplugged the machine while running.  After connecting the machine to electricity, I attempted to boot it.  Very early in the boot attempt, I see a screen with only "Invalid partition table!"  The boot does not progress further, and Ubuntu does not load.

I successfully started Ubuntu on the machine with the Live USB.  Can I restore normal machine function without reinstalling a new operating system and losing any stored data, user accounts, et cetera?  If so, how?

Comment: What does gparted show about the disk?

Comment: GParted has a rescue option to detect and restore corrupted partition tables IIRC, but before trying that you should make a full raw image of the whole disk to make sure you can revert it in case it fails and does more harm than good.

Comment: Before using GParted, and ***if*** the disk uses the GUID Partition Table (GPT), I recommend using `gdisk`, and in particular, its `v` option. See the [`gdisk` documentation on recovering damaged disks](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/repairing.html). `gdisk` provides better features for recovering damaged GPT data; but if the GPT data structures are really completely toast, using GParted's recovery tools -- or better yet, [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) -- may be in order. Be aware that you can dig yourself a deeper hole with any of these tools, so be cautious!